# Binary tree to circular doubly linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to make a circular doubly linked list using a binary tree using following function, But its throw Compilation error, given below the code.

```
/*Node is as follows:
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;

    Node(int x){
        data = x;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};*/

Node *bTreeToCList(Node *root)
{
    if(!root) return NULL;
    stack<Node *> s;
    s.push(root);
    Node *temp=NULL, *cdll=NULL, *head=NULL;

    while(!s.empty()){
        while(temp){
            s.push(temp->left);
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        temp = s.top(); s.pop();
        int data = temp->data;
        temp = temp->right;
        if(!head){
            head = cdll = new Node(data)
        }
        else{
            cdll->right = new Node(data)
        }
    }
    cdll->right = head;
    head->left = cdll;
    return head;
}
```

Compilation Error:

> Compilation Error prog.cpp: In function ‘Node* bTreeToCList(Node*)’:
>   prog.cpp:164:40: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘Node::Node(int&)’
>                head = cdll = new Node(data)
>                                           ^ prog.cpp:6:8: note: candidate: Node::Node()  struct Node
>           ^ prog.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided prog.cpp:6:8: note: candidate: constexpr Node::Node(const
>   Node&) prog.cpp:6:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from
>   ‘int’ to ‘const Node&’ prog.cpp:6:8: note: candidate: constexpr
>   Node::Node(Node&&) prog.cpp:6:8: note:   no known conversion for
>   argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Node&&’ prog.cpp:167:40: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘Node::Node(int&)’
>                cdll->right = new Node(data)
>                                           ^ prog.cpp:6:8: note: candidate: Node::Node()  struct Node
>           ^ prog.cpp:6:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided prog.cpp:6:8: note: candidate: constexpr
>   Node::No.................

Comment: After uncommenting `struct Node` definition, only errors I get is missing semicolons after `new Node(data)` (and about `stack`, I assume you meant `std::stack`). Please provide [mcve]

Comment: You and the compiler seem to disagree about the existence of the constructor. It's possible that you're including a different header than you're assuming.